# To show bind mount source path for mount after v2.25.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

UPDATE, I'm reopening this question as `findmnt` is not the answer.

Basically the summary of the OP is that since version 2.25.2, mount does not show its source path any more:

```
$ mkdir -v /export/crash
mkdir: created directory '/export/crash'

$ mount -v --bind /export/crash /var/crash
mount: /export/crash bound on /var/crash.

$ mount | grep crash 
/dev/sdb2 on /var/crash type ext3 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered)
```

Before mount v2.25.2, it used to report the mount source:

```
$ mount | grep crash 
/export/crash on /var/crash type ext3 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered)
```

This is very inconvenient for me, as

- I was able to do `umount mount_source` before, but now I can only do `umount mount_target`
- I bind mount from certain source as read-only, and I have a script to turn RW on and off for those bind mounts. But with the new mount (v2.25.2+), I'm no longer able to do that.

And the `findmnt` is not the answer to my above problems:

```
$ findmnt | grep crash
└─/var/crash   /dev/sdb2[/crash]   ext3    rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered
```

I.e., it doesn't show that `/var/crash` comes from `/export/crash` either. (NB, if you test with bind mount from `/tmp/crash` or alike, you will see `/tmp/crash` in the source, but I need to see the `/export` part, my mount point).

Please help.

**== The following is the original OP ==**:

The syntax for bind mount has always been

```
mount --bind olddir newdir
```

However, I noticed a difference in how `mount` reports the bind mounts between Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic and Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid, i.e., mount v2.25.1 and mount v2.25.2.

In Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic, the `mount` reports the bind mounts like this:

```
$ mount | grep www
/my/path/to/www on /var/www type none (rw,bind)

$ mount -V   
mount from util-linux 2.25.1 (libmount 2.25.0: selinux, assert, debug)
```

However in Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid, it is like this:

```
$ mount | grep www 
/dev/sda11 on /var/www type ext3 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered)

$ mount -V   
mount from util-linux 2.25.2 (libmount 2.25.0: selinux, assert, debug)
```

I.e., the bind mount source path is missing from the `mount` report. For both cases, I use the exact syntax for bind mount as above.

How can I make `mount` show bind mount source path in Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid ( mount v2.25.2) then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is grep the */proc/self/mountinfo*:

```
$ less /proc/self/mountinfo | grep /my/mount
221 84 8:3 /bind/source /my/mount rw,relatime shared:32 - ext4 /dev/sda3 rw,data=ordered
```

Comment: THX! Welcome aboard with my +25 :)

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered using `findmnt`?

`mount` stores its information in /proc/mounts (or /proc/self/mounts), which is symlinked to /etc/mtab. `mount` will simply cat this file, and it no longer stores bind information.